# JavaFX regularly get mouse position

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I'm writing a program that entails updating the mouse's position, but I can't find a way to retrieve the mouse coordinates regularly. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'regularly'? Also when do you need to know if the mouse has moved? Is it when the mouse moves over a specific node? Because then you'd need a mouse listener on that node. Is it when the mouse moves from being over one node to being over another? Then you might need one listener for each node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following listener to your base pane:

```
   basePane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {

        //x and y mouse positions
        e.getX();
        e.getY();

    });
```